# Is there a formula for the popcorn (Thomae) function like there is for the Dirichlet function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

There is the following expression for the Dirichlet function:

$\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb Q}(x) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\cos(k!\pi x)\right)^{2j}\right)$

I'm wondering if there is also an expression (in the form of a limit / series or whatever) for the popcorn function.

Comment: The popcorn function has at most countably many discontinuities, so it can be written as a limit of continuous functions. In fact, this can be done rather easily: Write ${\mathbb Q} = \{r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots \},$ and let $f_n(x)$ be the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n\}.$ Then the popcorn function is equal to $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n.$ But I don't know of a "nice representation" in the sense of using "elementary functions". **(continued)**

Comment: For what it's worth, since every $f_n$ is continuous, each $f_n$ is the limit of polynomials (even with rational number coefficients), so the popcorn function can be written as a double limit of polynomials with rational coefficients, and it is easy to see that this can be done in a constructive/explicit way, since [this is true for each $f_n$](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol6/Mayans/Weierstrass.html) and there are certainly constructive/explicit enumerations of the rational numbers. **(continued)**

Comment: For a constructive/explicit representation of the Dirchlet function as a triple limit of polynomials having rational coefficents, see footnote #263 on page 89 [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2025807/f91.image). Regarding my previous note (I can no longer edit it), each $f_n$ is NOT continuous, but each $f_n$ can be written as a limit of continuous functions (even with elementary functions, as hand drawn pictures will certainly suggest; think about Dirac delta "function" representations), and so "double limit of polynomials ..." should be "triple limit of polynomials ...".